# Is this answer about the limiting factor correct?

Tags: homework, ecology, nutrition

[image]
The graph shows the result of adding both phosphorus and nitrogen to different algae populations. I have a hard time figuring out why the correct answer is C, I thought that  groups 4 and 5 would have nitrogen as a limiting factor because adding it increases their growth. Help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please avoid posting text as images. Images are not searcheable and the format can be unpleasant. While it is easy to read in your case, nobody needs to know that you have 48% of battery left! Also, it may give a feeling that you're not putting much effort in the posting a nice question and this is probably why you got a down vote (the down vote was not from me). Also, "Help me please" makes it feel like your begging for help which is never really welcome on SE sites. You might want to edit all that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you, and think that there is a mistake in the "*Correct answer*". The interpretation in the "*Explanation*" seems to be correct though ("*Algae at locations 4 and 5 exhibited growth in response to fertilization with nitrogen.*"), so I think that there is a typo/mistake in the "*correct answer*". The answer should be **D**.

Normally within ecology (and especially in reference to nutrients, such as  nitrogen and phosphorus), *limiting factor* refers to the substance/nutrient that is in short supply within a particular environment, and is therefore limiting the potential growth of organisms. For examples, see any ecological textbook or [Blumenthal et al (2001)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444504869500054) (as an article example, picked at random). The concept of *limiting factors* is related to [Liebig's_law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum), which states that growth of organisms is determined by the scarcest resource, and not the total level of resources.

When performing a couple of searches now, I see some instances though where the term *limiting factor* is used on the opposite way, in reference to toxic substances. One example of this is [Imadi et al (2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128031582000011), where monomeric aluminum reduces root growth due to aluminum toxicity. This is not the most common use of the term though.

Comment: You might want to mention Liebig's Law of the Minimum here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum).

Comment: @arboviral Good call - now added.